# Correct overlay layers

Tags: html, css

I want to do as the picture, but does not go

[image]

[Here is a live example of what is](http://vk.cc/1AHpLE).

Answer (score 1):

You could give a background-color to #wrapper to replace the white default background-color.

Actually, it 'll be easier to let the background-image in another container and let that container overlap a few pixels the slider. it means to rethink slicing and layout structure.